# Why "proximate" refers to centesimal?

Tags: etymology, numbers

I mean, when I read "proximate" I think about "proximity".. why does it refers exactly to the 3rd digit in a number?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with using proximate that way.  Can you provide a link or example usage?

Comment: Possibly you have misinterpreted the sentence, so could you provide the sample sentence in the edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never encountered this usage.  If it's used that way at all, it's as a form of jargon.

Comment: A quick hunt through online dictionaries doesn't find this usage either.

Comment: right, so it's a google translator problem when translating from portuguese "centesimal" to english..

Answer (score 2):

One of the meaning of *proximate* is "nearly accurate, approximate."
I can imagine that *proximate* could be understood as "accurate to the third digit," while *accurate* could mean "showing all the digit."

I have never found *proximate* to mean "to the third digit," though.